# ObservableCollection<double []>, как его корректно вывести в DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

При попытке указания DataGrid.ItemsSource значения в датагрид не выводятся, а выводится информация о структуре массива. Как вывести сами значения?
Не использую класс, так как изначально сколько будет значений в строке не известно, это задает пользователь.

Comment: А как вы себе представляете датагрид из двумерного массива, коим собственно в итоге и является ваша коллекция массивов?

Comment: Автогенерацию полей средствами биндинга у вас не выйдет. Делайте свой контрол/делайте атачед/пишите код в code-behind, который создаст в коде колонки и заполнит их.